# Why is mcrypt_encrypt() putting binary characters at the end of my string?

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

Here is a PHP demo script that encrypts and decrypts data:

```
<?

$encryptionkey = 'h8y2p9d1';

$card_nbr = "1234";
echo "original card_nbr: $card_nbr <br>\n";

$card_nbr_encrypted=encrypt_data($card_nbr);
echo "card_nbr_encrypted: $card_nbr_encrypted <br>\n";

$card_nbr_decrypted=decrypt_data($card_nbr_encrypted);
echo "card_nbr_decrypted: $card_nbr_decrypted <br>\n";

$len=strlen($card_nbr_decrypted);
echo "length: $len <br>\n";



function encrypt_data($text){
  global $encryptionkey;
  $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
  $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
  $encrypted_text = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $encryptionkey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
  return $encrypted_text;
}

function decrypt_data($text){
  global $encryptionkey;
  $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
  $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
  $decrypted_text = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $encryptionkey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
  return $decrypted_text;
}

?>
```

The output is:

```
original card_nbr: 1234
card_nbr_encrypted: vY¨(Z$<§G3-žÃ-Éù3Ý2Ê×rz¨VÛ
card_nbr_decrypted: 1234  (and 28 binary characters)
length: 32
```

The output is successfully decrypted, but 28 binary characters are added to the end.  This can most easily be seen in Firefox, when viewing HTML source.
The string length of 32 also demonstrates this.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: see if that can be of any help http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: @Mian_Khurram_Ijaz I don't see why that would help

Comment: the output is actually in binary format so to make it safe accross network base64_encode is helpful the encrypt and decrypt is working fine so i thought if binary chars is the issue then use base64..

Comment: I read ECB mode is flawed, instead it's recommended to use CBC, or CBF. See why with a working implementation here: http://www.slideshare.net/ircmaxell/cryptography-for-the-average-developer (total newbie myself)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The returned string is padded out to fill `n * blocksize` bytes using the null character `\0` so that is why you are seeing the extra data.

If you run `$card_nbr_decrypted= rtrim($card_nbr_decrypted, "\0");` it should return the actual data.

Comment: A solution using `rtrim` is, of course, broken if you want to encrypt arbitrary binary data that might actually end in some number of nulls. In that case, you should either transmit the length of the string out-of-band and `substr` back down to that length (easy, but leaks the length of the string), or do the padding yourself before encrypting — I recommend using the PKCS#7 padding method as it's easy to understand.

Comment: The problem with PKCS#7 is that the bozos that wrote and maintain mcrypt did provide support for it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a [known problem](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php#78415). Use `rtrim()` after decoding to remove the excess NULs.

Answer (score 2):

You're receiving null bytes because you're using **Electronic Code Block (ECB)** for your [block cipher mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation), which pads the end of your plaintext to fit into the block size. In your case the block size is 256 bits because you're using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`.

You can avoid this padding problem all together if you use **Cipher Feedback (CFB)** mode — `MCRYPT_MODE_CFB` — no null bytes, no need to trim. But, with CFB you should [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) your encrypted data, to verify it hasn't been tampered with [(see "Mallet")](http://www.pvv.ntnu.no/~asgaut/crypto/thesis/node16.html). You can find an example of a working implementation at: [Cryptography For The Average Developer](http://www.slideshare.net/ircmaxell/cryptography-for-the-average-developer-1).

Also of note, ECB mode is considered less secure because it can [reveal data patterns](http://bobnalice.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/friends-don%E2%80%99t-let-friends-use-ecb-mode-encryption/). Plus, ECB (and CBC since it also pads) can be vulnerable to [padding oracle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack).

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you are using binary data when:

mcrypt_encrypt — Encrypts plaintext with given parameters

You can use base64_encode($text) for use plaintext.

Comment: Encoding is not the same thing as encrypting.

Comment: I know. But if You uses mcrypt_encrypt It is useful to send $text as a base64 plaintext to avoid problems with encoding.
You can use base64_encode($text) or rtrim() as others users propose.